# Adding additional dropdowns on selection

Tags: apex, visualforce, custom-object

I have a cascading dropdown (two dropdowns with one dependant on the other) in one of my objects which allows users to select a product, this information is the passed onto another object via flat text.

Is it possible to have multiple dropdowns groups? i.e. so when they select product x from dropdowngroup1, another dropdown (dropdowngroup2) will appear allowing the user to select product y (second item) this time.

[image]
So when `Service of Interest > Product` have been selected, a new set of dropdowns should appear as shown in the red box.

This data could be passed into an array which I can print out later.

Comment: Any Reason a multi select pick-list wouldn't work.  This builds the flat text array for you.  The output is 'Choice1;Choice2;Choice3'

Comment: @sfdc_ninja My appoligies, missed out a key peice of information. Please check updated post.

Comment: Imran -- your question isn't clear enough -- be more specific with a more complete example

Comment: @crop1645 updated.

Comment: You'd need a Visualforce page for this. The code is actually straightforward, but I don't have the willpower to type it in on a mobile device. Basically, you make a list of records in a controller, and use apex:repeat in the page itself. There must be dozens of examples of how to do this on the net.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using apex:repeat on visualforce page and have a list with records that you will use just for rendering these picklists.

```
<apex:outputPanel id="picklists">
     <apex:repeat value="{!serviceOrders}" var="i">
         <apex:inputField value="{!i.Service_of_Interest__c}"></apex:inputField><br></br>
         <apex:inputField value="{!i.Product__c}"></apex:inputField><br></br>
     </apex:repeat>
</apex:outputPanel>
```

in your controller:

```
List<Service_Order__c> serviceOrders {get;set;}
```

you need to add one record by default in your constructor

```
list.add( new Service_Order__c());
```

and when user selects Product you can add another record and rerender "picklists" output panel,
this way it will add another set of picklists. You will need to use actionFunction for this.
And when user will click save on the page you can loop through this list and create string from all selected Product values:

```
String selectedProducts = '';
for ( Service_Order__c so: serviceOrders ) {
    selectedProducts += so.Product__c + ';';
}
```

hope this will help

Comment: That loop leaves a trailing semi-colon. Do this: `String[] products = new String[0]; for(service_order__c so: serviceOrders) products.add(so.Product__c); selectedProducts = String.join(products, ';');`

Comment: @PaulBoiko My appologies for the delayed response, I am looking into your solution at the moment. Could you expand on the actionFunction side of the solution? Also would there be a way to implement this using just the standard controller?